# Deserializing XML attribute 'xsi:type'

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

This is my first time to ask on stackoverflow and also the first time to work with xml files , so I don't think it can get worse than that.
I need to deserialize some long XML but the part thats bugging me is the following:

```html
<CastleConfigSub xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xsd/c5c.xsd" Format="1">
  <ConfigFile Name="EdgeDetection">
    <Interfaces>
      <Interface Name="EdgeDetectionModule">
        <Doc />
         <Functions>
          <Function Name="MonitorNoChanges">
            <Doc>This Function checks that no edge has been detected at the specified                    digital channel for a specific time in msec
             1. DigitalChanelToWatch: This is the digital Input channel to monitor                      edges on it.
             2. TimeOut: This is the monitoring Period for the edges on the digitial                    input channel.
            </Doc>
            <Args>
              <Arg xsi:type="ArgEnum" Name="DigitalChanelToWatch"                                      Enum="DigitalInChannelID" />
              <Arg xsi:type="ArgValue" Name="TimeOut" EncodedType="uint32"                               Unit="msec" />
            </Args>
           </Function>
          </Functions>
        </Interface>
      </Interfaces>
    </ConfigFile>
  </CastleConfigSub>
```

```
public class CastleConfigSub
{
    [XmlElement("Options")]
    public Options options = new Options();

    [XmlElement("ConfigFile")]
    public ConfigFile configFile= new ConfigFile();


} 
public class ConfigFile
{
    [XmlElement("Doc")]
    public string doc {get; set;} 
    [XmlElement("History")]
    public History history = new History();
    [XmlElement("Includes")]
    public Includes includes = new Includes();
    [XmlElement("Options")]
    public Options options = new Options();
    [XmlElement("DataTypes")]
    public DataTypes dataTypes = new DataTypes();

    [XmlArray("Interfaces")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Interface")]
    public List<Interface> interfaces = new List<Interface>();


}
 public class Interface
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string name="";
    [XmlElement("Doc")]
    [XmlArray("Functions")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Function")]
    public List<Function> functions = new List<Function>();
}
public class Function
{

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string name="";
    [XmlElement("Doc")]
    public string doc="";
    [XmlArray("Args")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Arg")]
    public List<Arg> args = new List<Arg>();
}
public class Arg
{
    [XmlAttribute ("xsi:type")]
    public string type = "";
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string name ="";
    [XmlAttribute("EncodedType")]
    public string encodedType="";
    [XmlAttribute("Enum")]
    public string enumName ="";
    [XmlAttribute("Unit")]
    public string unit="";

}
```

I know everthing is so messy but i couldnt do any better :/.

Comment: What specifically is your problem ? You may want to use the tool XSD.exe supplied with the .net framework to generate C# classes from an XML file (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: D you really need both 'interfaces' & 'interface'?  What about 'functions' & 'function'.  And 'args' & 'arg'.  Changing XmlArrayItem to XmlElement removes these duplicates tags.

Comment: @jdweng Yes i do need them because this is not the full xml file , the full xml file has many interfaces, functions and args so I guess i need it this way.

Comment: @PhillipH My problem is that this code results in 'There was an error reflecting type exception'

Comment: Type exception are  usually when a string won't convert to a number.  You can still can have arrays without the double tags (Args, Arg).  Don't need the Args tag.  Simply remove Args (along with XmlArray) and make Arg an XmlElement (not XmlArray).

Comment: @jdweng Do you suggest this even if the xml contains multiple Args , functions ,etc?

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes!!!   You still have a List<> object with all the info.  You have all the info in the class.  Using XmlArray just adds more text in the xml with no additional info in the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
public class CastleConfigSub
{
    public ConfigFile ConfigFile { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public byte Format { get; set; }
}
public class ConfigFile
{
    public List<Interface> Interfaces { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Interface
{
    public object Doc { get; set; }
    public List<Function> Functions { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Function
{
    public string Doc { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem("Arg")]
    public List<Arg> Args { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
[XmlInclude(typeof(ArgEnum))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ArgValue))]
public class Arg
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ArgEnum : Arg
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Enum { get; set; }
}
public class ArgValue : Arg
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string EncodedType { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

I do not know how many times Interface and Function elements exists. So I made the List collection.

Comment: That worked fine.If you can please explain why it has to be this way?Is 'xsi:type' kind of a keyword or a special attribute that i can't just get like the other ones?

Comment: The `XmlSerializer` class uses the `xsi:type` attribute to determine what type of object to deserialize from the XML instance element containing the attribute. The type must be present in the derivation hierarchy. (The prefix xsi is used for the XML Schema instance namespace, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance and applies to XML instance documents intended to conform to specified XML schemas.) Also, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is a good one, and helped me to solve my issue, but I've got extra work to handle different namespaces in xml element and it's attribute value, so my solution is here:

Having following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RootType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://my.custom.namespace.com">
  <description>some description</description>
  <values>
    <field>some field</field>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:double">1000.00</value>
  </values>
</RootType>
```

The deserialized objects set is following

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RootType", Namespace = "http://my.custom.namespace.com")]
public sealed class Root
{
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("values")]
    public Value[] Values { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Value
{
    [XmlElement("field")]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("value", IsNullable = true)]
    public ValueProperty ValueProperty { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(CustomDouble))]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://my.custom.namespace.com")]
public class ValueProperty
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "double", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
public class CustomDouble : ValueProperty
{
}
```